# webview2.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript not working on same class as browser.ObjectForScripting

Tags: c#, .net, webview2

I'm converting our old .NET browser based control to use webview2.  Most of it works except a part of browser handling where we retrieve data from clicking on an icon on the web page.

On our old browser control, we set browser.ObjectForScripting = MyClass.  MyClass has a method called Execute(string command).

When a user clicks on the icon that is visible on the page, the Execute method gets hit and all is well.

Converting to webView2 however, this does not work.  I've added the proper attributes to MyClass, ie [ComVisible(true)] and [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)], but clicking on the icon does not hit the Execute method.

I've initialized webView2 properly via EnsureCoreWebView2Async(), called webView2.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("browser", this), and set various event handlers that do get hit, but I can't figure out why the Execute method doesn't work. I've also tried creating a new class instead of using "this", but it still doesn't work.

The webView2.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived event kind of works, but doesn't give me the script I want to be handled exactly and I have to do a lot of things that I don't want to in that event handler.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public partial class MyClass
{
   ...
   public void Execute(string params)... // does not work with webView2

   ...
   private void WebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
      webView2.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("browser", this);
   }
   ...
}
```

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust"), ComVisible(true)]
public partial class MyClass
{
   public MyClass()
   {
      browser.ObjectForScripting = this;
   }

   public void Execute(string params)... // works with old browser control

}
```

Comment: Please show the javascript that uses this.

Comment: @PoulBak It's not js that we've written and it comes from an external site.  I'm trying to debug the page source to find it, but I'm having no luck finding it in the .js files that VS shows...it's very cryptic.

Comment: @PoulBak my guess is that it's doing something like this? "<html><head><script>" +
            "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
            "</script></head><body><button " +
            "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
            "call client code from script code</button>" +
            "</body></html>";